# C++ recognize shape from points

Tags: c++

I'am trying to find out an algorithm to recognize circle in array of points.

Lets say that I've got points array where circle could or could not be stored (that also means array doesn't have to store only circle's points, there could be some "extra" points before or after circle's data).

I've already tried some algorithms but none of them work properly with those "extra" points. Have you got any ideas how to deal with this problem?

EDIT// I didn't mention that before. I want this algorithm to be used on circle gesture recognition. I've thought I would have data in array (for last few seconds) and by analysing this data in every tracking frame I would be able to say if there was or was not a circle gesture.

Comment: are you referring to points on a graph?

Comment: if you are, a keyword you should search for is [Triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I calculate the geometric mean (not the aritmetic mean) for each X and Y component.
I choose geometric mean because one feature is that small values ​​(with respect to the arithmetic mean ) of the values ​​are much more influential than the large values.

This lead me to the theoretical center of all points: circ_center

Then I calculate the standard deviation of distance of each point to center: stddev. This gives me the "indicator" to quantify the amount of variation. One property of circle is that all circumference point is at the same distance of it's center. With standard dev I try to test if your points are (with max variance threshold: max_dispersion) equally distance.

Last I calculates the average distance of points inside max_dispersion threshold from center, this give me the radius of the circle: avg_dist.

Parameters:
max_dispersion represents the "cicle precision". Smaller means more precise.
min_points_needed is the minimun number of points valid to be considered as circumference.

This is just an attempt, I have not tried. Let me know.

I will try this (in pseudo language)

```
points_size = 100; //number_of_user_points
all_poins[points_size]; //coordinates of points

//thresholds to be defined by user
max_dispersion = 20; //value of max stddev accepted, expressed in geometric units
min_points_needed = 5; //minimum number of points near the circumference

stddev = 0; //standard deviation of points from center
circ_center; //estimated circumference center, using Geometric mean
num_ok_points = 0; //points with distance under standard eviation
avg_dist = 0; //distance from center of "ok points"

all_x = 1; all_y = 1;   
for(i = 0 ; i < points_size ; i++)
{
    all_x = all_x * all_poins[i].x;
    all_y = all_y * all_poins[i].y;
}
//pow(x, 1/y) = nth root
all_x = pow(all_x, 1 / points_size); //Geometric mean
all_y = pow(all_y, 1 / points_size); //Geometric mean
circ_center = make_point(all_x, all_y);

for(i = 0 ; i < points_size ; i++)
{
    dist = distance(all_poins[i], circ_center);
    stddev = stddev + (dist * dist);
}
stddev = square_root(stddev / points_size);

for(i = 0 ; i < points_size ; i++)
{
    if( distance(all_poins[i], circ_center) < max_dispersion )
    {
        num_ok_points++;
        avg_dist = avg_dist + distance(all_poins[i], circ_center);
    }
}
avg_dist = avg_dist / num_ok_points;

if(stddev <= max_dispersion && num_ok_points >= min_points_needed)
{
    circle recognized; it's center is circ_center; it's radius is avg_dist;
}
```

Comment: I will totaly try that solution. Would you please make any explanation (summary would be great) of this pseudocode you made? I still not understand it properly.

Comment: I added some explanation, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can we assume the array of points are  *mostly*  on or near to the circumference of the circle?

A circle has a center and radius.  If you can determine the circle's center coordinates, via the intersection of  perpendiculars of two chords, then all the **true** circle points should be equidistant(r), from the center point.

The false points can be eliminated  by not being equidistant (+-)tolerance from the center point.

The weakness of this approach is how well can you determine the center and radius?  You may want to try a least squares approach to computing the center coordinates.

Comment: No, we cannot assume that. Array could obtain any data and I have to recognize if there was or was not a cirle.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the initially stated question, my approach would be to iterate through the points and derive the center of a circle from each consecutive set of three points. Then, take the longest contiguous subset of points that create circles with centers that fall within some absolute range. Then determine if the points wind consistently around the average of the circles. You can always perform some basic heuristics on any discarded data to determine if a circle is actually what the user wanted to make though.

Now, since you say that you want to perform gesture recognition, I would suggest you think of a completely different method. Personally, I would first create a basic sort of language that can be used to describe gestures. It should be very simple; the only words I would consider having are:

- Start - Denotes the start of a stroke

  - Angle - The starting angle of the stroke. This should be one of the eight major cardinal directions (N, NW, W, SW, S, SE, E, NE) or Any for unaligned gestures. You could also add combining mechanisms, or perhaps "Axis Aligned" or other such things.
- End - Denotes the end of a stroke
- Travel - Denotes a straight path in the stroke

  - Distance - The percentage of the total length of the path that this particular operation will consume.
- Turn - Denotes a turn in the stroke

  - Direction - The direction to turn in. Choices would be Left, Right, Any, Previous, or Opposite.
  - Angle - The angle of the turn. I would suggest you use just three directions (90 deg, 180 deg, 270 deg)
  - Tolerance - The maximum tolerance for deviation from the specified angle. This should have a default of somewhere around 45 degrees in either direction for a high chance of matching the angle in a signature.
  - Type - Hard or Radial. Radial angles would be a stroke along a radius. Hard angles would be a turn about a point.
  - Radius - If the turn is radial, this is the radius of the turn (units are in percentage of total path length, with appropriate conversions of course)

Obviously you can make the angles much more fine, but the coarser the ranges are, the more tolerant of input error it can be. Being too tolerant can lead to misinterpretation though.

If you apply some fuzzy logic, it wouldn't be hard to break just about any gesture down into a language like this. You could then create a bunch of gesture "signatures" that describe various gestures that can be performed. For instance:

```
//Circle
Start Angle=Any
Turn Type=Radial Direction=Any Angle=180deg Radius=50%
Turn Type=Radial Direction=Previous Angle=180deg Radius=50%
End

//Box
Start Angle=AxisAligned
Travel Distance=25%
Turn Type=Hard Direction=Any Angle=90deg Tolerance=10deg
Travel Distance=25%
Turn Type=Hard Direction=Previous Angle=90deg Tolerance=10deg
Travel Distance=25%
Turn Type=Hard Direction=Previous Angle=90deg Tolerance=10deg
Travel Distance=25%
End
```

If you want, I could work on an algorithm that could take a point cloud and degenerate it into a series of commands like this so you can compare them with pre-generated signatures.